# Correct SQL statement for unique row with lowest date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server table with years of daily data time series for different stock symbols. Some symbols have more data than others because their time series begins or ends at different dates than other symbols.

I want to get a single row of all the symbols from a SQL Server database and the first date entry in the table. I tried this SQL statement

```
sql = "SELECT date, symbol  
       FROM results_eod  
       WHERE date = (SELECT MIN(date) FROM results_eod s2 
                     WHERE symbol = s2.symbol)  
       ORDER BY symbol"
```

but this returns a unique row of all the symbols where their min date are the same, e.g. **all** have the **same** min date of 2008-1-1. The rest of the symbols seem to be filtered out if the starting date is not 2008-1-1.

What is the correct SQL?

Comment: Just one row, or one row per symbol?  Can any symbol have multiple rows with the same date stamp?

Comment: One row per symbol, with its corresponding lowest date in the table for it. No, dates are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your where clause is wrong.  You need...

```
WHERE results_eod.symbol = s2.symbol
```

If there are multiple tables with the column `symbol` the table in the current scope has precedence. Essentially, by not specifying the table in your WHERE clause, you had...

```
WHERE s2.symbol = s2.symbol
```

It always pays to fully qualify you references. Don't get lazy and miss out the table names / aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Try this also. The output should be with all symbols  with lowest date per symbol, each on distinct row.

```
select symbol,min(date)
from results_eod
group by symbol
order by date
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple tables referenced in a query, *all* columns should be qualified (i.e. have the table alias).  This advice is particularly important for correlated subqueries.

So:

```
SELECT r.date, r.symbol 
FROM results_eod r
WHERE r.date = (SELECT MIN(r2.date)
                FROM results_eod r2
                WHERE r2.symbol = r.symbol
               )  
ORDER BY r.symbol;
```

Otherwise, a reference -- such as `symbol` in the subquery might be to the wrong table.

With an index on `results_eod(symbol, date)`, this is probably the most performant way to write the query.  However, people often write this as:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by r.symbol order by r.date) as seqnum
      from results_eod r
     ) r
where seqnum = 1;
```